# WPF Custom/User Control for button with text and icon. Which one should I choose?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-controls

I'd like to refactor the following code using a custom control for the button.

Xaml file: `LoginWindow.xaml`

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource BlackLoginButton}" Click="btnLogin_Click" IsDefault="True">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="text1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Source="../../../Assets/Images/apply.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Button>
```

Code behind: `LoginWindow.xaml.cs`

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login();
}
```

I particular I'd like to have a structure like this:

```
<local:CustomButton>
    Grid.Column="0"
    IsDefault="True"
    Style="{DynamicResource BlackLoginButton}"
    Click="btnLogin_Click"
    Text="ciao" 
    Image="../../../Assets/Images/apply.png">
</local:CustomButton>
```

I try to use both Custom Control and User Control.

Here is my `UserControl` xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="foo.View.CustomUserControl.IconButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BlackLoginButton}">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=Button, Path=Text}" />
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Button, Path=Image}" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Mhira3D.View.CustomUserControl
{
    public partial class IconButton
    {
        public static DependencyProperty ClickProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Click", typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
            typeof(IconButton));

        public static DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(IconButton));

        public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(IconButton));

        public IconButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public RoutedEventHandler Click
        {
            get { return (RoutedEventHandler) GetValue(ClickProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ClickProperty, value); }
        }

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get { return (ImageSource) GetValue(ImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
            set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem of this structure is that I cannot use `Button` property (I did not inherit from button), for example I cannot use `IsDefault`.

I think it could be an alternative use a `CustomControl`, to use the button property in a better way, like this (in thi example I put only the `Image` property):

```
public class IconButtonCustom : Button
{
    static IconButtonCustom()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IconButtonCustom), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(IconButtonCustom)));
    }
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return GetValue(SourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconButtonCustom));
}
```

And the style in `Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customUserControl:IconButtonCustom}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BlackLoginButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customUserControl:IconButtonCustom}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=Button, Path=Text}" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=Button, Path=Image}" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I have some questions:

1. Which of these methods is the more suitable to create my custom button?
2. Using both methods, I have problem mapping the click function, in fact I got the `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` because WPF cannot convert the string `btnLogin_Click` in the function `Click`.
3. I've never used `Generic.xaml`, is my example correct or should be improved in some way?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to pass in a different image for each instance?

Comment: A different image, text and click function ;)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want a custom control then? Because you can do all that with just a button style template.

Comment: No, there isn't. How can I do all the associations with only a style template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, so most Framework elements have a handy-dandy property called [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that exists for instances like these where we could use a way to piggy-back something into a template without having to go and declare additional dependency properties and such.

So if we take a default `Button` style template (Right-Click the button->Edit Template->Edit a Copy) we see a `ContentPresenter` in there that will generally pass any `CLR` object. So we're good there for your text, or whatever else you want.

We now have multiple options to accomplish your goal. One would be to simply pass in your two elements this way (in pseudo);

```
<Button>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <TextBlock/>
     <Image/>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Except that seems a bit tedious. So we move into the `Style` Template option and instead do something like this to it;

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!-- We set a default icon/image path for the instance one isn't defined. -->
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="../../../Assets/Images/apply.png"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
             <!-- This is where we've added an Image to our Button with it's source bound to Tag. PS - In everything else like Silverlight, WP, UWP, Embedded etc, it's just {TemplateBinding Tag} -->
                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notice the added `Image` element with it's `Source` set to `{TemplateBinding Tag}` along with a setter at the top specifying a string path to what could be a default image.

So now at the instance we could just do;

```
<Button Content="Blah Blah Blah" Click="Click_Handler"
        Style="{StaticResource SpecialButtonStyle}"/>
```

...and we would get a button, with the default icon, and your click handler. Except now we need to display different icons for each instance. So we could do something like;

```
<Button Content="Blah Blah Blah" 
        Click="Click_Handler"
        Tag="../../../Assets/Images/DIFFERENTIMAGE.png"
        Style="{StaticResource SpecialButtonStyle}"/>
```

Except that still seems a little daunting. So we could take it a step further and make your asset strings into resources. Add the mscorlib namespace to you dictionary as something like `xmlns:sys" prefix and you could do this;

```
<sys:String x:Key="imageONE">../../../Assets/Images/imageONE.png</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="imageTWO">../../../Assets/Images/imageTWO.png</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="imageTHREE">../../../Assets/Images/imageTHREE.png</sys:String>
```

This does us a few benefits. One, much easier maintenance in case you need to change the file path/name for one of those icons. You can do it in just one spot and it will inherit to all instances. Instead of having to track down each instance it's hard set at. It also allows us to invoke these at the instance as a resource, so now our `Button` instance would look like this;

```
<Button Content="Blah Blah Blah" 
        Click="Click_Handler"
        Tag="{StaticResource imageTWO}"
        Style="{StaticResource SpecialButtonStyle}"/>
```

Voila, you're done. However another observation you should consider, is your file paths. I would definitely use [Pack Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead. As long as your path is correct and your build action on the image is also you should be set.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: I found the problem with data conversion :(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/edec50f6-d1c7-4891-a814-a9c6f154baf9/binding-image-source-with-templatebinding-in-xaml?forum=wpf), At the end the fix was Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}". You can fix the answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: @Rowandish Oh right, WPF, for anything else it's just `{TemplateBinding Tag}` but glad you got a solution. :)